# Neo4j: when merging does not overwrite node properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to modify a MERGE Cypher query so that the property field is not overwritten.

To update the node properties I use the following cypher query:

`MERGE (n:Person {name:"me"})
ON MATCH SET n+={id:"2"}
ON CREATE SET n={name:"me", id="1"}
RETURN n`

If I call the same query again with
`ON MATCH SET n+={id:"3"}`
the id will be updated.

How to make a query that adds the property if it is not existing but does not overwrite it if it is already present?

Answer (score 2):

First, you can just use plain properties, no need to do {map}..

Secondly, in case the MERGE creates the node, he will already have the property name:me on it :

```
MERGE (n:Person {name:'me'})
ON MATCH SET n.id = 2
ON CREATE SET n.id = 1
RETURN n
```